# Cannot Find Favicon for particular website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome

I have looked for favicon high and low, I have looked in the Chrome cache to see if it is there. I have viewed the Page Info in Chrome.

No matter what I do I cannot find the favicon, download and add to the source code for this website:
**URL REMOVE FOR PRIVACY**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why it doesn't seem to show up in Chrome's developers tools, but this should be it.

www.mywebsite.com/favicon.ico

A favicon can often be located on the root domain as simple "favicon.ico".